# Time of response taking too long time - Laravel Api

Tags: php, laravel, rest, response

I'm building a laravel API, and I'm testing my requests from Postman.
Simple request taking a too long time to get some response(about 200~300 ms). I have the same API in Java that gives the same responses in 30 ms maximum. Anyone have any idea what be happening?

response time:

[response time image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDiIP.png)

Controler:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Setor;

class SetorController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){  
        return Setor::all();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because the DB query takes a lot of time.
Try to change the method to simple returning value:

```
public function show(){  
    return 'ok';
}
```

Then measure request time. Did it decrease?

Comment: Looks like framework initialisation takes a lot of time. Have you enabled OPcache in PHP? Which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: My version of PHP is  7.2.12